# Amazon MWS Integration

Tags: amazon-mws

So, I want to use Amazon's MWS API in my chrome extension tool. But I'm confused about how it works with just getting the Seller ID and MWS Auth Token from users.

Since MWS Request requires to enter the Seler ID, MWS AuthToken, AWS Accesskey and Secret key.

Is there a way to get the both access and secret key using the seller id and authtoken?

Or, are there any other syntax that only requires seller id and auth token.

Thank you in advance for those who responds. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't.  The MWS Access Key ID and Secret Key come from YOUR account.  They allow you, as a developer to access MWS.  If you want to access a customers account, you'll need them to authorize access to you by giving them your account number.  They will return to you an MWS Auth Token, which you'll send on every request along with their account number and your Access Key ID and Secret Key which you'll need to create.  The whole process is spelled out right here: https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/faq.html

Comment: Awesome :D Thanks :D